# Having issue while trigger from one repo to another repo

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I wrote following workflow in repo1 to trigger into repo2. While executing it's giving following error:

> Creating settings.xml with server-id: github Writing to
> /home/runner/.m2/settings.xml Error: No file in
> /home/runner/work/server/server matched to [**/pom.xml], make sure you
> have checked out the target repository

```
name: Trigger to QA Repo from dev repo
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - add-bat-wf
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Step 1 - Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'
          cache: maven
      - uses: convictional/trigger-workflow-and-wait@v1.3.0
        with:
          owner: myOrg
          repo: QA_Repo
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          workflow_file_name: workflow.yml
          ref: master
          wait_interval: 10
          inputs: '{ "suite": "src/test/APITest.xml", "platform": "api"}'
          trigger_workflow: true
          wait_workflow: true
```

Comment: seems the issue is in the `repo2` workflow. Please post the workflow definition or double check you have checkout the code as the error message suggest